# Javascript objects from API to tabledata js objects

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I want to convert data from API to tabledata.
the var serverdata is going to be filled by an foreach loop.

first time loops fills serverdata.

```js
var serverdata = {
    0: {certname: "server1", environment: "production", name: "id", value: "PROD\server1$"}
    1: {certname: "server1", environment: "production", name: "fqdn", value: "server1.prod.com
    2: {certname: "server1", environment: "production", name: "domain", value: "prod.com
    3: {certname: "server1", environment: "production", name: "osfamily", value: "windows"}
    4: {certname: "server1", environment: "production", name: "uptime", value: "11 days"}
    5: {certname: "server1", environment: "production", name: "network", value: "192.168.0.1"}
    6: {certname: "server1", environment: "production", name: "virtual", value: "physical"}
    7: {certname: "server1", environment: "production", name: "hostname", value: "server1"}
    8: {certname: "server1", environment: "production", name: "serverphase", value: "in use"}
    }
```

The first output needs to be:

```
var tabledata = {
    0: {hostname: "server1", id: "PROD\server1$", fqdn: "server1.prod.com", domain: "prod.com", osfamily: "windows", uptime: "11 days", network: "192.168.0.1", virtual: "physical", serverphase: "in use" }
    }
```

Then the loop fills serverdata with new data.

```
var serverdata = {
    0: {certname: "server2", environment: "production", name: "id", value: "acc\server2$"}
    1: {certname: "server2", environment: "production", name: "fqdn", value: "server1.acc.com
    2: {certname: "server2", environment: "production", name: "domain", value: "acc.com
    3: {certname: "server2", environment: "production", name: "osfamily", value: "windows"}
    4: {certname: "server2", environment: "production", name: "uptime", value: "13 days"}
    5: {certname: "server2", environment: "production", name: "network", value: "192.168.0.2"}
    6: {certname: "server2", environment: "production", name: "virtual", value: "physical"}
    7: {certname: "server2", environment: "production", name: "hostname", value: "server2"}
    8: {certname: "server2", environment: "production", name: "serverphase", value: "in use"}
    }
```

The next output needs to be:

```js
var tabledata = {
    0: {hostname: "server1", id: "PROD\server1$", fqdn: "server1.prod.com", domain: "prod.com", osfamily: "windows", uptime: "11 days", network: "192.168.0.1", virtual: "physical", serverphase: "in use" }
    1: {hostname: "server2", id: "acc\server2$", fqdn: "server2.acc.com", domain: "acc.com", osfamily: "windows", uptime: "13 days", network: "192.168.0.2", virtual: "physical", serverphase: "in use" }
    }
```

and so on.

Comment: Is `serverdata` going to be an array of objects?

Comment: serverdata is een array of objects. serverdata is going to filled then i need to convert it and put the end result in tabledate var.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Since i am not sure how you are using it , i ll try to give you a full usage example

From what i understood from your question i think you can break this into 2 steps.

First you want to build a function that transforms one serverdata entry into a tabledata entry

```
const fromServerDataEntryToTableDataEntry = (serverdata) => {
    return Object.values(serverdata).reduce((acc, cv) => 
           ({...acc, [cv.name]: cv.value}), {})
}
```

Then you can use this next function, it gets an array of serverdatas and parse each one of them into the desired tabledata entry format, we now have an array of objects where each object is a tabledata entry, as final step we convert that array into the desired final object

```
const buildTableData = (arrayOfServerDatas) => {
    let dataTableArray = arrayOfServerDatas.map(ele => { 
        return fromServerDataEntryToTableDataEntry(ele)
    })
    return Object.assign({}, dataTableArray)
}
```

Comment: thx, for the function but the output is not an JS object how do jou convert it because JSON.parse() dont work?

Comment: i dont understand what you mean by "is not a js object" , if i run it with your serverdata example as a parameter i get an object

Comment: Sorry my bad :). i am bid confused because the out come is {id: "server1", fqdn: "server1.prod.com", domain: "prod.com"} and not 0: {id: "server1", fqdn: "server1.prod.com", domain: "prod.com"}

Comment: I think your problem lies in what is an object, you are a bit confused by it, when you have the time you can check https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp for a better understanding how objects work.

Comment: Thx for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply write a function that takes one serverdata array and returns one element for your tabledata:

```
const convert = (serverdata) => {
    // define columns, or pass them if they differ
  const columns = [
    "id",
    "fqdn",
    "domain"
  ];
  let ret = {};
  columns.forEach((item, index) => {
    ret[item] = serverdata[index]["value"];
  });
  return ret;
}

let serverdata = {
    0: {certname: "server1", environment: "production", name: "id", value: "PROD\server1$"},
    1: {certname: "server1", environment: "production", name: "fqdn", value: "server1.prod.com"},
    2: {certname: "server1", environment: "production", name: "domain", value: "prod.com" }
    }

console.debug(convert(serverdata));
// or instead add to your tabledata array
```

Did I understand your question well and does this help you?

Comment: thx, for the function but the output is not an JS object how do jou convert it because JSON.parse() dont work?

Comment: The function returns a JS object (check other answer where you asked the same question). You can access it's properties by either `data.fqdn` or by `data[fqdn]`. In my example, try saving `convert(serverdata)` to a variable and outputting different properties, it may help you understanding what's going on.